# Java - Pausing a thread pool when it is executing with a JButton

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executor

I have a pause mechanism for my events(Runnable) but I am not sure how to use/call it when I need it to be called.

In my class, I have a run method that submits an arraylist full of events to an executor. (see run() on GreenhouseControls). When the Events are submitted, Thread.sleep(eventTime); is called and afterwards the action() inside the event is called.

My program requirement needs a mechanism that pauses all the threads with a method(which will be called by a method when clicked) which can be resumed later on with another button.

Does anyone know how to implement this mechanism?

Here are the files:

**GreenhouseControls.java**

```
package control;
/**
 *  In this exercise we take a different design approach to GreenhouseControls 
 *  
 *  Compiled/Tested using Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
 *  TME4 Folder is located in C:\COMP 308\
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import tme4.*;


/**
 * GreenhouseControls consists of the Greenhouse's status and methods that
 * control what actions will be performed inside the Greenhouse.
 * @author Ray Masiclat
 *
 */
public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller implements Serializable{
    /**
     * status is a Set of StatusPair objects which contains information about the
     * GreenhouseControls' status. The Default States are initialized in the default constructor.
     */
    private Set<StatusPair> status = new HashSet<StatusPair>();
    private static String file = "src/error.log";


    /**
     * Default Constructor -    initializes each state of the Greenhouse
     * 
     */
    public GreenhouseControls(){
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, Boolean>("light", false));
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, Boolean>("water", false));
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, Boolean>("fans", false));
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, Boolean>("windowok", true));
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, Boolean>("poweron", true));
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, String>("thermostat", "Day"));
        status.add(new StatusPair<String, Integer>("errorcode", 0));
        status = Collections.synchronizedSet(status);
    }

    /**
     * Prints out in the console how to use the program.
     */
  public static void printUsage() {
    System.out.println("Correct format: ");
    System.out.println("  java GreenhouseControls -f <filename>, or");
    System.out.println("  java GreenhouseControls -d dump.out");
  }
  /**
   * Takes in an errorcode and returns the appropriate Fix that will fix the
   * error that occured in the past.
   * @param errorcode
   * @return fix
   */
  public Fixable getFixable(int errorcode){
      Fixable fix = null;
      switch(errorcode){
      case 1:
          fix = new FixWindow(this);
          break;
      case 2:
          fix = new PowerOn(this);
          break;
      default:
          System.out.println("No Error");
          break;
      }
      return fix;
  }

  /**
   * shutdown - method creates a Logger that creates an error log which consists of information about the
   * reason of why the program was shut down. After logging the error information, it serializes
   * the current state of the program in order for it to be fixed/restored in the future.
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public void shutdown() throws IOException{
      System.err.println("System Shutting Down");
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ControllerException");
      FileHandler fh;
      try {
          fh = new FileHandler("src/error.log");
          logger.addHandler(fh);
          SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
          fh.setFormatter(formatter);
      } catch (SecurityException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      //Check for errorcode using getError method.
      int checkError = this.getError();
      if(checkError == 1){
          logger.info("Window Malfunction");
      } else if (checkError == 2){
          logger.info("Power Outage");
      } else {
          logger.info("No Error");
      }
     /**
      * Serialize the current state and output it onto the src/ directory as dump.out
      */
      ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/dump.out"));
      out.writeObject(this);
      out.writeObject(getEventList());
      out.close();
      System.exit(0);
  }

  /**
   * getStatus - returns the status Set which consists of information about the current state of the program.
   * @return status
   */
  public Set<StatusPair> getStatus(){
      return status;
  }

  /**
   * getError - Assigns an integer which will be used when logging the error.
   * The errorNum is retrieved using the status Set
   * @return errorNum
   */
  public int getError(){
      int errorNum = 0;
      //Iterate through the status Set
      for(StatusPair sp : status){
          //Check for the name "errorcode" and initializes errorNum from its status
          if(sp.getName().equals("errorcode")){
              errorNum = (int) sp.getStatus();
          }
      }
      return errorNum;
  }

  /**
   * getEventList - returns a List of Events in the program.
   * @return eventList
   */
  public List<Event> getEventList(){
      return eventList;
  }

  /**
   * Create a method in GreenhouseControls called setVariable to 
   * handle updating to this collection. Use the synchronization feature 
   * in java to ensure that two Event classes are not trying to add to 
   * the structure at the same time.
   * s - represents the name of the status
   * o - represents the status it is going to be replaced with
   * @param s
   * @param o
   */
  public void setVariable(String s, Object o){
      for(StatusPair sp : getStatus()){
          if(sp.getName().equals(s))
          {
              sp.setStatus(o);
          }
      }
  }

  /**
   * addStatus - Adds a new status in the status Set and it is used
   * if the program cannot find a name in the status Set.
   * @param name
   * @param status
   */
  public void addStatus(String name, Object status){
      getStatus().add(new StatusPair<String, Object>(name,status));
  }

  /**
   * run -  creates a thread array which will be used to run Events from
   *        the text file. Then a for loop is created to fill up the thread
   *        array with Events on each index. Then the thread is started once
   *        an index is initialized. After an event is added in to the thread
   *        array it is removed from the events list.
   */
public void run(){
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    if(eventList.size() == 1){
        exec.submit(eventList.get(0));
        eventList.remove(eventList.get(0));
    } else {
        for(Event e : eventList){
            exec.submit(e);
        }
    }
    exec.shutdown();

    /*while(eventList.size() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++){
            exec.submit(eventList.get(i));
        }
    }*/
      /*Thread[] threads = new Thread[eventList.size()];
      while(eventList.size() > 0)
      for(int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++){
          threads[i] = new Thread(eventList.get(i));
          threads[i].start();
          eventList.remove(i);
      }*/
  }
} ///:~
```

**Event.java**

```
/**
 *  Make Event implements Runnable so that each type of event provides 
 *  its own timing. Each event file should be a class of its own. Change 
 *  the rest of the design to simplify this model.
 *  
 *  Assignment: TME4
 *  @author Ray Masiclat
 *  @studentid 3231308
 *  @date July 27, 2015
 *  
 *  
 *  Compiled/Tested using Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
 *  TME4 Folder is located in C:\COMP 308\
 */
package tme4;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import gui.*;
import control.*;
/**
 * Event class that implements Runnable and Serializable
 * @author Ray Masiclat
 *
 */
public abstract class Event implements Runnable, Serializable{
    /**
     * eventTime - represents time it takes for the program to wait and then
     *              call its action method.
     */
    protected long eventTime;
    protected GreenhouseControls gcontrol;
    protected boolean suspended = false;
    /**
     * Event class constructor which is used to initialize the Event's eventTime and
     * GreenhouseControls object which is used for the Event to have access to its status
     * variables.
     * @param gc
     * @param eventTime
     */
    public Event(GreenhouseControls gc,long eventTime){
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
        this.gcontrol = gc;
    }

    /**
     * getTime - returns the event's eventTime initialized from the constructor.
     * @return eventTime
     */
    public long getTime(){
        return eventTime;
    }

    /**
     * setTime - sets the eventTime
     */
    public void setTime(long eventTime){
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }
    /**
     * run -    Event class' run method is called when the Event is added in to the Thread
     *          and then "started". This method puts the Thread to sleep for however long the
     *          eventTime is. Afterwards, once it is done, it tries to run the Event's action
     *          method. If the action method throws an error, it is caught by the try-catch
     *          block which calls the GreenhouseControls object's shutdown which outputs an error.log
     *          file and serializes the current state of the GreenhouseControls object to a dump.out file.
     */
    public void run(){

        try {
            synchronized(this){
                while(suspended){
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(eventTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            this.action();
        } catch (ControllerException e) {
            //Use shutdown to create error log
            try {
                gcontrol.shutdown();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void suspend(){
        suspended = true;
    }

    public synchronized void resume(){
        suspended = false;
        notify();
    }

    /**
     * abstract method used to call an Event's action method in the run method.
     * @throws ControllerException
     */
    public abstract void action() throws ControllerException;
} ///:~
```

(Pastebin: [GreenhouseControls.java](http://pastebin.com/prBMNpU7)
                    and [Event.java](http://pastebin.com/KJ8Yzne0))

Comment: It would be better if you posted the relevant code in your question, posting the complete code files is good for context but it's harder to get help when users have to look through a 200+ line file.

Comment: @yvesmancera The relevant code is in the question i believe, I thought it would be easier to understand to have a better view of the whole class. Please ask me anything about my question that is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

boolean stop = false;

You can use a suspending/stopping object, like so

```
public class Stopping {

  public synchronized void checkStop() {
    if (stopped) {
      wait(); // wait until stop has been cleared
    }
  }

  public synchronized void setStop(boolean val) {
    stop = val;
    if (val) {
      notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Create one of these and share it with all your threads, making sure to call checkStop() frequently. Alternatively, you could make the methods in this class static, and then your threads wouldn't need an object reference - they could just call Stopping.checkStop();

Comment: Should I add this as an Inner class inside my GreenhouseControls?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, unless you're going with the static option. But your way wouldn't necessarily be wrong; you just need to make sure that every thread is using the same object/lock

Comment: Man i think your solution makes sense but I can't wrap my head around how I'm going to implement it! I'll keep trying! Thank you very much!